# column not NULL using Having instead of where

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a query in which i am having problems, i want to 
find **distinct** Leaf_category_id so i want to do **group by** operation.

How do i modify this query to replace where with having. and doing group by operation not null

```
select Leaf_Category_id,totalOrders,totalCartAdditions,clicks,clicks * 100/ t.s as `click_percent`
from leafCategoryAnalysis 
CROSS JOIN (SELECT SUM(clicks) AS s FROM leafCategoryAnalysis) t 
where Leaf_Category_id is not NULL
order by clicks
```

Comment: Try `DISTINCT` instead of `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as well formatted text.

Answer (score 1):

```
select Leaf_Category_id,sum(totalOrders),sum(totalCartAdditions),sum(clicks),sum(clicks) * 100/ sum(t.s) as `click_percent`
from leafCategoryAnalysis 
CROSS JOIN (SELECT SUM(clicks) AS s FROM leafCategoryAnalysis) t 
where Leaf_Category_id is not NULL
group by Leaf_Category_id
```

Try this. I haven't tried myself. Hope it helps.
I just applied sum function on other columns.